# PageLink constructor: An error occurred while try to resolve java website in web 8

Tags: content-delivery, web8

We are in the process of upgrading to SDL 8 from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. while upgrading content delivery website which in java we are getting below error inside cd_linking.jar

```
com.tridion.linking.PageLink
PageLink constructor: An error occurred
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.tridion.storage.wrapper.WrapperFactory.isWrapperConfigured()Z
at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.runWrappers(StorageManagerImpl.java:248)
at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.getDAO(StorageManagerImpl.java:153)
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:176)
at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:122)
at com.tridion.linking.PageLink.init(PageLink.java:83)
at com.tridion.linking.PageLink.&lt;init&gt;(PageLink.java:52)
at org.apache.jsp.en.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:198)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**OverrideDiscoveryService is false inside cd_link_cofig.xml file**

Comment: we are trying to update our content delivery website from 2013 sp1 to web 8.After replacing new jar files and removing unwanted jar files we are getting above error message.